# How to refer to object property within object

Tags: java, object

I have a class named `compte`:

```
public class compte {
    private double somme;
    private double limit;
    private double withdrawn;


    public compte(double amt, double lmt, double wdr){
        somme = amt;
        limit = lmt;
        withdrawn = wdr;
    }
}
```

I have two 'compte's in my 'client' object:

```
public class client {
private static String nom;
private static String prenom;
private static String adresse;
private static compte chequing;
private static compte savings;
private static client[] tab;
private static int pin;
private static String nomfich;
private static int accountNum;
private static int forVal;


public client(String adr, String nomF, String prn, compte ch, compte sav, int nip, int accNum){
    adresse = adr;
    nom = nomF;
    prenom = prn;
    chequing = ch;
    savings = sav;
    pin = nip;
    accountNum =accNum;
}
```

Let's say that iv'e already set up one client in the first slot of a client array 'tab'(`tab[0]`). I want to refer to the 'somme' in the 'chequing' compte. I tried `tab[0].chequing.somme`, but that does not seem to work.

In relatively new with Java so sorry if this seems super dumb xD.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: " but that does not seem to work." -- What is the error that you are getting? What does it tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your code using those classes, and you did not post the error, so here's my guess: you declared the fields private.

Read about the access control modifiers:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html
Particularly, the "Access Levels" table near the top of the page.

You will need to provide access methods (getXXX/setXXX) or change the modifier, which depends on how you intend to use them.

Answer (score 0):

As `chequing` and `somme` are `private` variables, they would not be visible to the class where you are calling them. You have two choices :

- Write `getter` and `setter` methods, like :

  `public double getSomme(){
       return this.somme;
   }`

and

```
public void setSomme(double somme){
    this.somme = somme;
}
```

- Make all the variables public, though it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Add getter, setter in your class and access attributes by getter `client.getTab()[0].getChequing().getSomme();`

```
public class compte {
    private double somme;
    private double limit;
    private double withdrawn;


    public compte(double amt, double lmt, double wdr) {
        somme = amt;
        limit = lmt;
        withdrawn = wdr;

    }

    public double getSomme() {
        return somme;
    }

    public void setSomme(double somme) {
        this.somme = somme;
    }

    public double getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(double limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public double getWithdrawn() {
        return withdrawn;
    }

    public void setWithdrawn(double withdrawn) {
        this.withdrawn = withdrawn;
    }
}

public class client {
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String adresse;
    private compte chequing;
    private compte savings;
    private client[] tab;
    private int pin;
    private String nomfich;
    private int accountNum;
    private int forVal;


    public client(String adr, String nomF, String prn, compte ch, compte sav, int nip, int accNum) {
        adresse = adr;
        nom = nomF;
        prenom = prn;
        chequing = ch;
        savings = sav;
        pin = nip;
        accountNum = accNum;
    }

    public client() {
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    public compte getChequing() {
        return chequing;
    }

    public void setChequing(compte chequing) {
        this.chequing = chequing;
    }

    public compte getSavings() {
        return savings;
    }

    public void setSavings(compte savings) {
        this.savings = savings;
    }

    public client[] getTab() {
        return tab;
    }

    public void setTab(client[] tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
    }

    public int getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getNomfich() {
        return nomfich;
    }

    public void setNomfich(String nomfich) {
        this.nomfich = nomfich;
    }

    public int getAccountNum() {
        return accountNum;
    }

    public void setAccountNum(int accountNum) {
        this.accountNum = accountNum;
    }

    public int getForVal() {
        return forVal;
    }

    public void setForVal(int forVal) {
        this.forVal = forVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your code:

1. all the fields are private, thus unaccessible from outside the class where they are defined,
2. the fields in class client are also static, meaning that they are shared between all instances of the class.

Apart from that, class names usually start with a capital letter, but that, of course, is just a convention.